# Extract land cover data from Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth, land-cover

I have latitude-longitude coordinates for a certain region with me. Is it possible that when I enter this data in Google Earth, I can somehow extract the land cover class associated with each coordinate?

Or how can I access the land cover data (if GE already has it online)?

I am new to Google Earth.

Comment: Unless you've got a KML file or KML network link that is putting land cover data on your Google Earth, you can't do it.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Google Earth does not have land use/cover data. It has detailed satellite images that covers most of the globe. You can only visualize your points on Google Earth to see in which region/part of the earth are located. And even if there is a land use/cover data, you still cannot extract those raster information to the point, as you can do in other GIS software like ArcGIS or QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

Though land cover/land use (LCLU) maps are produced from classification of satellite imagery, I don't know if you can find such information in Google Earth. However, you can access this information worldwide from different sources:

- GlobCover (from European Space Agency, global coverage): http://due.esrin.esa.int/page_globcover.php. 2009 seems the last version.
- NASA land cover maps: see http://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/view.php?datasetId=MCD12C1_T1

For Europe, you can have a look on:

- Corine Land Cover (Europe only): http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/corine-land-cover-2006-raster-2

Another source might be OpenStreetMap, which has [landuse](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:landuse) tags (and also the less used [landcover](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Proposed_features/landcover) tag). An interesting project is this land use map derived from OpenStreetMap:

- http://osmlanduse.org/.

Finally, many countries also produced their own LCLU maps/database. You may check for the countries you want...

As mentioned by @ahmadhanb, after having download these data, you might use a GIS software such as QGIS or ArcGIS to extract land cover classes by location.

Comment: Use of Google Earth is compulsory for me. I need to test the reliability of its data against the landcover data that I already have from Globcover (which you mentioned in your answer).

Comment: Does it have to be an automatic comparison between GE imagery and Globcover? If yes, you could "print screen" Google imagery using a script and then make the comparison.